# Unable to run HashiCorp Vault in Synology NAS

Tags: docker, hashicorp-vault, synology

I have downloaded the latest hashicorp/vault:latest image from docker hub and I am trying to deploy the container in my synology NAS. During the container creation, my settings are below

1. Environment Variables

```
VAULT_RAFT_NODE_ID=node1
VAULT_RAFT_PATH=/docker/vault/data    (NAS Folder)
VAULT_ADDR=http://10.10.10.5:8200
VAULT_API_ADDR=http://10.10.10.5:8200
VAULT_CLUSTER_ADDR=http://10.10.10.5:8201
```

2. Folder Mapping

```
/docker/vault/config => /vault/config
/docker/vault/data => /vault/data
/docker/vault/file => /vault/file
/docker/vault/logs => /vault/log
```

3. Port Mapping

```
Container Port  => Local Port
8200 => 8200
8201 => 8201
```

4. Execution Command

```
server --cap-add=IPC_LOCK -config=/docker/vault/config/config.hcl
```

5. Config.hcl

```
listener "tcp" {
  address     = "10.10.10.5:8200"
  tls_disable = "true"
}

disable_mlock = true

api_addr = "http://10.10.10.5:8200"
cluster_addr = "https://10.10.10.5:8201"
ui = true
```

If I do not specify the configuration and try to run **server -dev** and HashiCorp Vault container is working without any issues.  I am trying to deploy production equivalent to test my application.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to fix the issue.  It may be helpful for others.

Create local.json in /vault/config folder.  The sample content is below

```
{
  "api_addr": "http://10.10.10.5:8200",
  "cluster_addr": "http://10.10.10.5:8201",
  "disable_mlock": true,
  "listener":
    {
      "tcp": 
        {
          "address": "[::]:8200",
              "tls_disable": true
        }
    },
  "storage":{
      "raft":
        {
          "node_id": "node1",
          "path": "/vault/data"
        }
  },
  "ui": true
}
```

During the docker container creation, do not launch immediately.  After creation, export the settings into your local computer and delete the container.

Open the container settings file and update the below values

```
"CapAdd" : "IPC_LOCK"
 "privileged" : true
```

Save the settings and in the docker, import the settings file and run the container.

Launch the browser and access the vault using http://:8200.

In the first run, you have to specify the no.of keys creation etc., and click the "Initialize" button to generate the root key token and keys.

Now you have production ready HashiCorp vault ready and running in Synology NAS.